# ReactJS - Compile to Windows Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I read about compile ReactJS to standard app. I founded docs about compile to mobile applications, but I need to compile it to Windows application.
How can I do this?

Comment: You could probably use [electron](http://electron.atom.io/) to package up a reactjs app.  But this topic is very broad.

Comment: What about http://reactjs.net/getting-started/download.html